# Filter based on 2 JSON properties after using json_extract

Tags: sql, sqlite

Imported database tables :

```
id           | JSON
-------------|---------
Signed 32int | Raw JSON
```

It is easier to search via the properties of the JSON data than by id of the row itself. Each piece of JSON data contains (for this demo):

```json
json: {
displayProperties: {},
hash: "foo"
itemType: "bar"
}
```

When I select I would like to matching hash, and then filter those results by a matching `itemType`.

My query :

```sql
SELECT json_extract(ItemDefinition.json, '$') 
 FROM ItemDefinition, json_tree(ItemDefinition.json, '$')
  WHERE json_tree.key = 'hash' AND json_tree.value IN ${hashList}
```

However this returns every item that has a matching hash value. From here, I would like to also filter by key: `itemType` and value: "19". So I tried :

```sql
SELECT json_extract(ItemDefinition.json, '$') 
 FROM ItemDefinition, json_tree(ItemDefinition.json, '$')
  WHERE json_tree.key = 'hash' AND json_tree.value IN ${hashList}
   AND WHERE json_tree.key = 'itemType' AND json_tree.value = 19
```

But this isn't syntactically correct, let alone output what I am looking for. Error:

> SQLITE_ERROR: near "WHERE": syntax error

Comment: Not a `Javascript` or `JSON` question.  That being said, its not syntactically correct.  You need "select A from B where C **and** D" but you have "select A from B where C **and where** D"

Comment: @Tibrogargan So youre saying to just make the AND WHERE a AND instead? I tried 

```WHERE (json_tree.key = 'hash' AND json_tree.value IN ${hashList})
            AND (json_tree.key = 'itemType' AND json_tree.value = '19')``` 

but that returns nothing even thought I know for a fact that there are objects in the db that satisfy those conditions

Comment: Yes, just make the "AND WHERE" an "AND" instead.  Can't speak to the issue w/ no results, I looked at this question because it was tagged JavaScript.  If I was gonna guess I'd say start with how you're using `json_tree` (but I know nothing about it, that's a complete guess)

Comment: Oh.  Just took another look at your WHERE clause.  It's returning nothing because "WHERE X = Y AND X = Z" is contradictory, it will never return anything.  You need something more like "where ( A = B and C = D ) or ( A = X and C = Y )"

Answer (score -1):

The title of the question turned out to not be accurate to what I was looking for. I miss-understood what [json_tree](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jtree) actually did. json_tree actually builds a new object with values that are filled in by the database.

What I was actually looking for was to filter by a specific value in the json column, which can be achieved by [json_extract](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jex). `json_extract('{column}', $.{filterValue})` will pull the raw json object out of the json column

This is the query that is working for me now:

```sql
SELECT json_extract(ItemDefinition.json, '$') 
    FROM ItemDefinition, json_tree(ItemDefinition.json, '$')
       WHERE json_tree.key = 'hash' 
       AND json_tree.value IN ${hashList} 
       AND json_extract(ItemDefinition.json, '$.itemType') = 19
```

This selects the json column from ItemDefinition
Creates a json_tree from the json column
Filters results by json tree `key` and `value`
Finally filters by the property `itemType` from the raw json column

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).